# How to Populate QDateEdit Stored in QString again into a QDateEdit

Tags: qt, qstring, qdate

I have 2 QDateEdit which are Date_dob and Date_doj.
I am storing the value using a Qstring shown below.

```
QString str_dob(ui->DATE_dob->text());
QString str_doj(ui->DATE_doj->text());
```

Now i want to populate the same into ui->Date_dob and ui->Date_doj (after some editing event takes place). I have used ,

```
ui->DATE_dob->setText(s.at(2));
ui->DATE_doj->setText(s.at(5)); //where s is a string having data
```

but the data doesn't populate.

Any kind of suggestion will be extremely appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of the variable s?

Comment: @eyllanesc S just contains name,gender,dob,Department,Designation,Doj,Location and contact with index 0 to 7. I am getting proper date from the file as well. its just that its not populating in the ui again. All data is from the file. EDIT,ADD DELETE happens prooperly.

Answer (score 0):

For convert `QString` to `QDate` you can use [QDate::fromString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1). Then you can set date in `QDateEdit` with [QDate::setDate(const QDate &date)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#date-prop).

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong way the conversion.

**QDate to QString**

```
QString str_dob = ui->DATE_dob->toString("dd MM yyyy");
```

in the date format you should specify it else your conversation is default format. [Known Format you can use](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString)

**QString to QDate**

```
if( ui->DATE_dob->setDate(QDate::fromString(str_dob,"dd MM yyyy").year()\
,QDate::fromString(str_dob,"dd MM yyyy").month()\
,QDate::fromString(str_dob,"dd MM yyyy").day()){
// Your Conversation Succes
}
```

when QString to QDate you have to know date format in string else your conversation fail or wrong value you get.

Example: if Qstring is : 19/12/2017 than your format is "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: @ CMLDMR ui->Date_dob->toString(), toString is not popping up

Comment: @ CMLDMR no such option(toString) popping for ui->Date_dob

Comment: @ CMLDMR I am using a calender pop as well which as the format dd/MM/yyyy. This format is saved properly in the file. all the operation are also sucessful. Only problem is when i click EDIT Employee, that time all data except dob and doj is visible properly to edit.

Comment: @Lalaboy ui->Date_dob->date->date() to get date you need. and ui->Date_dob->setDate(QDate& date) to set date you need